# C code won't compile

Tags: c

Please help me to understand why the following code will not compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;
int main(void){
    int i,k,x,y,run,e,r,s,m,count=0;

char numbers[19][19];
for(i=0;i<19;i++){
          for (k=0;k<19;k++){
                   numbers[i][k]='.';
          }
}

void drawB(){
    printf("  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 \n");

     printf  ("0 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[0][0],numbers[0][1],numbers[0][2],numbers[0][3],numbers[0][4],
     numbers[0][5],numbers[0][6],numbers[0][7],numbers[0][8],numbers[0][9],
     numbers[0][10],numbers[1][11],numbers[1][12],numbers[1][13],numbers[0][14]
     ,numbers[0][15],numbers[0][16],numbers[0][17],numbers[0][18]);

     printf  ("1 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[1][0],numbers[1][1],numbers[1][2],numbers[1][3],numbers[1][4],
     numbers[1][5],numbers[1][6],numbers[1][7],numbers[1][8],numbers[1][9],
     numbers[1][10],numbers[1][11],numbers[1][12],numbers[1][13],numbers[1][14]
     ,numbers[1][15],numbers[1][16],numbers[1][17],numbers[1][18]);

               printf ("2 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     numbers[2][0],numbers[2][1],numbers[2][2],numbers[2][3],numbers[2][4],
     numbers[2][5],numbers[2][6],numbers[2][7],numbers[2][8],numbers[2][9],
     numbers[2][10],numbers[2][11],numbers[2][12],numbers[2][13],numbers[2][14]
     ,numbers[2][15],numbers[2][16],numbers[2][17],numbers[2][18]);

       printf ("3 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[3][0],numbers[3][1],numbers[3][2],numbers[3][3],numbers[3][4],
     numbers[3][5],numbers[3][6],numbers[3][7],numbers[3][8],numbers[3][9],
     numbers[3][10],numbers[3][11],numbers[3][12],numbers[3][13],numbers[3][14]
     ,numbers[3][15],numbers[3][16],numbers[3][17],numbers[3][18]);

       printf ("4 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[4][0],numbers[4][1],numbers[4][2],numbers[4][3],numbers[4][4],
     numbers[4][5],numbers[4][6],numbers[4][7],numbers[4][8],numbers[4][9],
     numbers[4][10],numbers[4][11],numbers[4][12],numbers[4][13],numbers[4][14]
     ,numbers[4][15],numbers[4][16],numbers[4][17],numbers[4][18]);

       printf ("5 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[5][0],numbers[5][1],numbers[5][2],numbers[5][3],numbers[5][4],
     numbers[5][5],numbers[5][6],numbers[5][7],numbers[5][8],numbers[5][9],
     numbers[5][10],numbers[5][11],numbers[5][12],numbers[5][13],numbers[5][14]
     ,numbers[5][15],numbers[5][16],numbers[5][17],numbers[5][18]);

       printf ("6 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[6][0],numbers[6][1],numbers[6][2],numbers[6][3],numbers[6][4],
     numbers[6][5],numbers[6][6],numbers[6][7],numbers[6][8],numbers[6][9],
     numbers[6][10],numbers[6][11],numbers[6][12],numbers[6][13],numbers[6][14]
     ,numbers[6][15],numbers[6][16],numbers[6][17],numbers[6][18]);

       printf ("7 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[7][0],numbers[7][1],numbers[7][2],numbers[7][3],numbers[7][4],
     numbers[7][5],numbers[7][6],numbers[7][7],numbers[7][8],numbers[7][9],
     numbers[7][10],numbers[7][11],numbers[7][12],numbers[7][13],numbers[7][14]
     ,numbers[7][15],numbers[7][16],numbers[7][17],numbers[7][18]);

       printf ("8 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[8][0],numbers[8][1],numbers[8][2],numbers[8][3],numbers[8][4],
     numbers[8][5],numbers[8][6],numbers[8][7],numbers[8][8],numbers[8][9],
     numbers[8][10],numbers[8][11],numbers[8][12],numbers[8][13],numbers[8][14]
     ,numbers[8][15],numbers[8][16],numbers[8][17],numbers[8][18]);

       printf ("9 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[9][0],numbers[9][1],numbers[9][2],numbers[9][3],numbers[9][4],
     numbers[9][5],numbers[9][6],numbers[9][7],numbers[9][8],numbers[9][9],
     numbers[9][10],numbers[9][11],numbers[9][12],numbers[9][13],numbers[9][14]
     ,numbers[9][15],numbers[9][16],numbers[9][17],numbers[9][18]);

       printf ("0 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[10][0],numbers[10][1],numbers[10][2],numbers[10][3],numbers[10][4],
     numbers[10][5],numbers[10][6],numbers[10][7],numbers[10][8],numbers[10][9],
     numbers[10][10],numbers[10][11],numbers[10][12],numbers[10][13],numbers[10][14]
     ,numbers[10][15],numbers[10][16],numbers[10][17],numbers[10][18]);

       printf ("1 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[11][0],numbers[11][1],numbers[11][2],numbers[11][3],numbers[11][4],
     numbers[11][5],numbers[11][6],numbers[11][7],numbers[11][8],numbers[11][9],
     numbers[11][10],numbers[11][11],numbers[11][12],numbers[11][13],numbers[11][14]
     ,numbers[11][15],numbers[11][16],numbers[11][17],numbers[11][18]);

               printf ("2 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[12][0],numbers[12][1],numbers[12][2],numbers[12][3],numbers[12][4],
     numbers[12][5],numbers[12][6],numbers[12][7],numbers[12][8],numbers[12][9],
     numbers[12][10],numbers[12][11],numbers[12][12],numbers[12][13],numbers[12][14]
     ,numbers[12][15],numbers[12][16],numbers[12][17],numbers[12][18]);

       printf ("3 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[13][0],numbers[13][1],numbers[13][2],numbers[13][3],numbers[13][4],
     numbers[13][5],numbers[13][6],numbers[13][7],numbers[13][8],numbers[13][9],
     numbers[13][10],numbers[13][11],numbers[13][12],numbers[13][13],numbers[13][14]
     ,numbers[13][15],numbers[13][16],numbers[13][17],numbers[13][18]);

       printf ("4 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[14][0],numbers[14][1],numbers[14][2],numbers[14][3],numbers[14][4],
     numbers[14][5],numbers[14][6],numbers[14][7],numbers[14][8],numbers[14][9],
     numbers[14][10],numbers[14][11],numbers[14][12],numbers[14][13],numbers[14][14]
     ,numbers[14][15],numbers[14][16],numbers[14][17],numbers[14][18]);

       printf ("5 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[15][0],numbers[15][1],numbers[15][2],numbers[15][3],numbers[15][4],
     numbers[15][5],numbers[15][6],numbers[15][7],numbers[15][8],numbers[15][9],
     numbers[15][10],numbers[15][11],numbers[15][12],numbers[15][13],numbers[15][14]
     ,numbers[15][15],numbers[15][16],numbers[15][17],numbers[15][18]);

       printf ("6 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[16][0],numbers[16][1],numbers[16][2],numbers[16][3],numbers[16][4],
     numbers[16][5],numbers[16][6],numbers[16][7],numbers[16][8],numbers[16][9],
     numbers[16][10],numbers[16][11],numbers[16][12],numbers[16][13],numbers[16][14]
     ,numbers[16][15],numbers[16][16],numbers[16][17],numbers[16][18]);

       printf ("7 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[17][0],numbers[17][1],numbers[17][2],numbers[17][3],numbers[17][4],
     numbers[17][5],numbers[17][6],numbers[17][7],numbers[17][8],numbers[17][9],
     numbers[17][10],numbers[17][11],numbers[17][12],numbers[17][13],numbers[17][14]
     ,numbers[17][15],numbers[17][16],numbers[17][17],numbers[17][18]);

       printf ("8 %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  %c  \n\n"
     ,numbers[18][0],numbers[18][1],numbers[18][2],numbers[18][3],numbers[18][4],
     numbers[18][5],numbers[18][6],numbers[18][7],numbers[18][8],numbers[18][9],
     numbers[18][10],numbers[18][11],numbers[18][12],numbers[18][13],numbers[18][14]
     ,numbers[18][15],numbers[18][16],numbers[18][17],numbers[18][18]);

}
void checkSurrounded (int x,int y){


//numbers [x-1,y-1 ] , numbers [x-1,y ] , numbers [x-1,y+1 ]
//numbers [x,y-1 ] , numbers [x,y ] , numbers [x,y+1 ]
//numbers [x+1,y-1, ] , numbers [x+1,y ] , numbers [x+1,y+1 ]

if(numbers[x][y]=='A'){
  if((numbers[x-1][y-1]=='B') && (numbers[x-1][y]=='B') &&
  (numbers[x-1][y+1]=='B') && (numbers[x][y-1]=='B') &&
  (numbers[x][y+1]=='B') &&  (numbers[x+1][y-1]=='B') &&
  (numbers[x+1][y]=='B')){
  numbers[x][y]='B';}

                      }
if(numbers[x][y]=='B'){
  if((numbers[x-1][y-1]=='A') && (numbers[x-1][y]=='A') &&
  (numbers[x-1][y+1]=='A') && (numbers[x][y-1]=='A') &&
  (numbers[x][y+1]=='A') &&  (numbers[x+1][y-1]=='A') &&
  (numbers[x+1][y]=='A')){
  numbers[x][y]='A';
  }
 }
 }
/**
 void checkArea(){
 //detect enemy stone
 //store in array
 //find adjacent enemy stones
 // store the enemy stones in the array
 //keep on doing this until there are no more enemy stones that are adjacent

for (s=0;s<19;s++) {
   for (m=0;m<19;m++) {
       if (numbers[s][m]=='A'){
             count++;
       }
   }
}



}//end fn

void checkAdjacent(int x, int y){
    if (numbers [x][y]=='A'){
       if((numbers[x][y-1]=='B' && numbers [x-1][y]=='B' && numbers[x][y+1]=='B' && numbers[x+1][y]=='B')){

       }
    }

}


void getUserInput(){

    int run=1;
    while(run){
               printf("Enter x coordinate\n");
               scanf("%d",&x);
               printf("Enter y coordinate\n");
               scanf("%d",&y);

               if((x>18 || y>18 || x<0 || y<0) && !( numbers[x][y]=='.' )){
                       printf("invalid imput\n");
               }

               else{
                    numbers[x][y]='B';
                    run=0;
                    drawB();


               }
    }
}
*/
void getCupInput(){
    //go through borad
    //starting from [0][0]
    //stop at first player stone
    //save as target x and target y
    //surround target x and target y
    //if already surrounded
    //start looking in borad again from last position
    //at end of board reset to [0][0]



    for(s=0;s<19;s++) {
      for(m=0;m<19;m++) {
         if (numbers[s][m]==0){
             count++;

          }
      }
  }


    x=x-2;
    y=y+2;
    numbers[x][y]='A';
    drawB();
}

 while(1){
        //getUserInput();
     getCupInput();
 }
         system("pause");

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: If it is not obvious to you that you should not write code like that, you have no business programming.

Comment: This code needs a lot of work. A lot.

Comment: Neil, I agree that the OP's code is ... ahem ... worrisome, to say the least. But the first time I saw a (5.25") floppy disk, I tried to remove it from its dust jacket. We all occasionally do things that seem stupid in hindsight. It's whether we get better that really matters.

Comment: Part of our charter is to be kind to the n00bs.  I've voted to reopen so that someone can tell OP to look up for loops, learn  how to use them, and come back and ask a better question.

Comment: @Norman Your charter perhaps - not mine.

Comment: @Marcelo One of my students actually succeeded.

Comment: Voting to re-open, _everyone has to start somewhere_. Its a valid question that will take a lot of time to answer, but someone might want to answer it. Thankfully, its not a duplicate :)

Comment: @Neil, nothing says you _must answer_ this question.

Comment: @Tim I haven't. And you seem to have your own private definition of the word "question".

Comment: @Neil, while I agree that the OP should pay one aspirin per printf for the answer to this, the question is quite clear .. "I need lots, and lots and _lots_ of links to books that will help me learn C". I didn't say the OP would _like_ the answers :)

Comment: What error message does your compiler give you?

Comment: Break it down in to smaller parts until you know what part of it doesn't compile.
When you've done that the answer is usually before your eyes.

Comment: Have you ever heard of loops?

Comment: This question is problematic not because the code is bad, but because "Why doesn't [big ass block of code] compile?" bereft of any indication of the working environment or error message is a really *bad* question. **@cc:** Please give us something to work with here. What's the error message? What compiler?

Comment: The question was asked an hour ago (at the time of this writing), please give the OP a little time to realize that they stirred up a hornet's nest :)

Comment: +1 for understanding closures so early on :-)  Unfortunately, C doesn't support closures.

Comment: @Norman I didn't answer. And I didn't vote to close. And I believe that the vast majority of people who program shouldn't -  nothing "snarky" (whatever that might mean) here.

Comment: @Neil oops sorry --- thought I saw your name on the close list.  Please accept apology.  Snarky is an Americanism; I don't think I can explain it.

Comment: @Neil: fortunately, someone with a clue was sitting next to me.

Comment: Obviously some kind of compiler bug, this code is both perfect and beautiful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `C` **function def cannot be nested** and that is what you are doing:

```
int main(void){                      // start of main fun def.
    int i,k,x,y,run,e,r,s,m,count=0;

char numbers[19][19];
for(i=0;i<19;i++){
          for (k=0;k<19;k++){
                   numbers[i][k]='.';
          }                         // end of inner for loop.
}                                   // end of outer for loop.


void drawB(){  //<--------- main() not yet completed..you've a new fun def.
```

Comment: Not if the asker is using GNU C, which supports nested functions :-)  I'm thinking the asker would be happier learning JavaScript, Python, or even Go (the programming language) first instead of C.

Comment: @Joey .. `system("pause");` is a very strong hint that the user is not using GNU C.

Comment: @Tim Wrong. This is boilerplate that the DevC++ IDE inserts into its projects - DevC++ uses GCC as the compiler. This sort of thing is one of the many, many reasons why no-one should be using DevC++.

Comment: @Neil, that would explain the commented out C++. Hereby redacted (well, would be, if I could still edit it).

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the very very beginnings of an attempt at a program for Go (the board game, not the recent programming language.)  Anyway, there are many issues with this code, but as far as failing to compile, I can see at least one.  With much, much code deleted, you very roughly have this:

```
int main(void) {
    char numbers[19][19];
    /* stuff */
}
void drawB(void) {
    printf("...", ..., numbers[X][Y], ...);
}
```

Inside `drawB`, the code cannot see the declaration of `numbers` inside of `main`, so the compiler will be giving you some sort of error about an undeclared variable `drawB`.  You need to move the declaration of `numbers` outside of `main`, so that both `main`, `drawB`, and all the other functions that reference `numbers` can see it.

@unicornaddict has pointed out that you've actually nested the defintion of `drawB` inside of `main`.  Perhaps you meant to do this, or perhaps it's just impossible to tell because of the inconsistent indentation inside of main.  Either way, once you fix the nesting problem, you'll have to move the declaration of `numbers` outside of your functions.  So, your code should now look a bit like this:

```
char numbers[19][19];
int main(void) {
    /* stuff */
}
void drawB(void) {
    printf("...", ..., numbers[X][Y], ...);
}
```